# How to password protect a file with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm generating an xls file and would like to protect it with a password before attaching it to an email. The excel package doesn't have this feature yet. Is there a walk around solution like packing the file into a password protected archive? Thanks!

Comment: This might help: https://pub.dev/packages/aes_crypt#-readme-tab-